# OpenShift, CORS, and master-config.yaml

Tags: cors, openshift

I'm having a issues when it comes to CORS and OpenShift.  I need to enable a website using corsAllowedOrigins in the master-config.yaml.

My question is how do I get to master-config.yaml?  I can't seem to find it in the OpenShift Web Console.  I also downloaded the  OpenShift command line, but I can't find any instructions online that show me how to navigate and edit master-config.yaml.

Answer (score 0):

Openshift is something that runs your servers. The servers run your applications. Some of them may be using restrictive CORS rules, some relaxed ones. The config you mention belongs to the server of a particular application, not to Openshift itself. If you have your application running already, so there's an image and a DeploymentConfig and at least one POD running the image, you probably need to create a ConfigMap that contains the configuration. Then the ConfigMap can be mounted as a folder, so your application would see it as a local resource. Have a look at: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/latest/dev_guide/configmaps.html for details.

Comment: Thanks for your input, this seems to help me get on the right path.  I must be missing something still.  I created a Config Map and added it to my application and rebuilt....I still see the same error.
This is what I added in my config map: 

    data:
      corsAllowedOrigins: .*

My understanding is this should allow CORS from any request.  Thoughts?  I can't find anything online to point me in the right direction

Comment: well, not right away. The application needs to actually read the config and, more importantly, respond with the header:
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
when a http request comes in. Can you give more details about your application? Have you written it yourself? One more favour to let us help you - can you do `oc export bc,dc,cm --all` end paste the results here into your question?